# Prime symbol LaTeX which is the best?

Tags: accents

I would like to know if it is formally correct to write the prime in this way,
for example:

```
$t^{'}$
```

?
Or maybe there is a better way?
Thanks

Comment: @Mico I am not sure it's really a duplicate as that asks for the difference between two equivalent forms but this question asks about a form that is incorrect

Comment: `x^{'}` is incorrect, the form is `x'` as shown in Heiko's answer. `x^{'}` is `x^{^{\prime}}}` so the prime is too small and too high.

Comment: I'm not sure where people got this suggestion, but Math.SE is full of such errors.

Answer (score 5):

The normal apostrophe is active in math to put a `\prime` is superscript position.
Additionally, it looks for following apostrophes to be added to the superscript:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[t', t'', t''', t''''\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

`t''` is short for `t^{\prime\prime}`.

The definitions from the LaTeX kernel:

```
\def\active@math@prime{^\bgroup\prim@s}
{\catcode`\'=\active \global\let'\active@math@prime}
\def\prim@s{%
  \prime\futurelet\@let@token\pr@m@s}
\def\pr@m@s{%
  \ifx'\@let@token
    \expandafter\pr@@@s
  \else
    \ifx^\@let@token
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\pr@@@t
    \else
      \egroup
    \fi
  \fi}
\def\pr@@@s#1{\prim@s}
\def\pr@@@t#1#2{#2\egroup}
```

Comment: I have upvote your answer also because I use often apostrophes added to the superscript. It is, for my opinion, the best solution.